# javascript error and double quotes in cookie values

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have 2 different sites, one site throwing a JavaScript error (which is out of my scope to handle) and when I try to login to this site, if the cookie value has a double quote in it, the login process is not successful. Whereas in another site where the JavaScript error is NOT present, the login process is successful. Is there any correlation between the JavaScript error and the double quotes?

This may be a very open ended question, unfortunately the code which is doing the above scenario is too huge to paste it here.

UPDATE:

```
public static Cookie createCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name,
   String value, boolean useDefaultPath) {

  logger.info("Cookie Name:" + name);
  logger.info("Cookie Value:" + value);
  logger.info("Cookie Domain:" + request.getServerName() + ":"
    + request.getServerPort());

  Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
  //String domain = request.getServerName();
  String domain = getSiteminderDomain(request);
  int idx = domain.indexOf('.');
  cookie.setDomain(domain.substring(idx+1));
  cookie.setMaxAge(DAY);
  if (useDefaultPath) {
   cookie.setPath(request.getPathInfo());
  } else {
   cookie.setPath("/");
  }
  logger.info("Cookie Value For Debug:" + value);
  return cookie;
}
```

Comment: Can you at least post the part of the code where you handle the cookies and what structure the cookie has when being stored/retrieved?

Comment: I have to ask, why are there double quotes in the cookie values to begin with? According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108207/definite-guide-to-valid-cookie-values, double quote is a special character and has to be handled as such.

Comment: @web_dev are you still having this problem? I recently had a similar one and have a way to solve it